# How to overlap two diagrams in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, encryption, data-visualization, bubble-chart

I have the following data frame which I am using to create a diagram using the code given below -

Data -

````
```structure(list(percents = c(52, 40, 34, 55, 48, 38, 17), label = c("Type 1", 
"Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 4", "Type 5", "Type 6", "Type 7")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))```
````

Code for 2018 diagram[image: 2018 diagram] -

````
```df %>% mutate(r = sqrt(percents), x = r + cumsum(lag(2 * r, default = 0))) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_circle(aes(x0 = x, r = r, y0 = r), size = 3, color = "gray") +
  geom_text(aes(x = x, y = r, label = paste0(percents, "%"), size = percents),
            fontface = "bold", color = "#643291") +
  geom_text(aes(x = x, y = 20, label = label), vjust = 0,
            fontface = "bold", color = "gray20", size = 3) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = x, xend = x, y = r + 3, yend = 18),
               color = "#643291", size = 2) +
  coord_equal() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits =c(-5, 25)) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(4, 8)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  labs(title ='2018')```


Then I have the following data for 2018 group B -

```structure(list(percents = c(48, 60, 66, 45, 52, 62, 83), label = c("Type 1", 
"Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 4", "Type 5", "Type 6", "Type 7")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))```
````

And I use a similar code as above (but different color to create another diagram)[image: 2018 group B]

````
 ```df %>% mutate(r = sqrt(percents), x = r + cumsum(lag(2 * r, default = 0))) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_circle(aes(x0 = x, r = r, y0 = r), size = 3, color = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(x = x, y = r, label = paste0(percents, "%"), size = percents),
            fontface = "bold", color = "#643291") +
  geom_text(aes(x = x, y = 20, label = label), vjust = 0,
            fontface = "bold", color = "gray20", size = 3) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = x, xend = x, y = r + 3, yend = 18),
               color = "#643291", size = 2) +
  coord_equal() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits =c(-5, 25)) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(4, 8)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  labs(title ='2018')```
````

****My question is that is there a way to overlap the two diagrams to show the two linear set of circles together vs side by side as I am doing right now?****

Thank you!

Comment: I would appreciate any kind of response here! Thank you!

Comment: What do you want the final product to look like? Do you want one long line of 14 circles, do you want two separate panels shown together, do you want the circles for each type to overlap? Regardless, probably best to combine your datasets into one with something like `bind_rows(a, b, .id = "source")`.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I want the circles to overlap with a common midpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may get you close to what you are looking for, but I'm not sure it's a great visualization.

```r
a <- 
  structure(
    list(
      percents = c(52, 40, 34, 55, 48, 38, 17), 
      label = c("Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 4", "Type 5", "Type 6", "Type 7")
    ), 
    class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = c(NA, -7L)
  )

b <- 
  structure(
    list(
      percents = c(48, 60, 66, 45, 52, 62, 83), 
      label = c("Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 4", "Type 5", "Type 6", "Type 7")
    ), 
    class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = c(NA, -7L)
  )

df <- 
  bind_rows(a, b, .id = "source") %>% 
  group_by(label) %>% 
  mutate(
    r = sqrt(percents), 
    max_r = max(r) # get the bigger circle of the pair
  ) %>% 
  group_by(source) %>% 
  mutate(
    x = max_r + cumsum(dplyr::lag(2 * max_r, default = 0)))
  )

ggplot(df) +
  ggforce::geom_circle(
    aes(
      x0 = x, 
      r = r, 
      y0 = 0, 
      color = source
    ),
    size = 1
  ) + 
  geom_text(
    data = filter(df, source == 1), 
    aes(
      x = x, 
      y = 2.5, 
      label = str_c(percents, "%"), 
      color = source
    ), 
    show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  geom_text(
    data = filter(df, source == 2), 
    aes(
      x = x, 
      y = -2.5, 
      label = str_c(percents, "%"), 
      color = source
    ), 
    show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      x = x, 
      y = -15, 
      label = label
    )
  ) + 
  labs(color = NULL) +
  coord_equal(clip = "off") + # so "Type" labels aren't clipped
  theme_void()
```